# Socket.io не работает с nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, angular2

Есть два сервера:

1. Фронтенд (тут два приложения на Ангуляр 2), они с помощью socket.io подключаются к бекенду (по ip, порт 80).
2. Бекенд (тут несколько серверов на Nodejs которые общаются между собой с помощью ZeroMQ а с помощью Socket.io c фронтендом).

На бекенде есть nginx, который и переадресует запросы на нужные сервисы. Но почему-то socket.io на фронтенде не может установить связь с сервером (хотя локально все работает).

Конечно же в настройке nginx'а (и для location / или для location /socket.io) я пишу:

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

в http:

```
 map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
                default upgrade;
                ''      close;
        }
```

Это не помогает. В чем может быть дело?
PS внутри сервера nodejs работают по https протоколу, сам сайт по http. Nginx проксирует на локальные секрвисы

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Пришлось сервер с сокетами выносить на отдельный поддомен. Тогда все доходит нормально.

Comment: Это как-то неправильно, у меня и на одном домене всё работает, лучше дайте нерабочий конфиг целиком

Comment: вы просто на один порт запускали 2 сервера, очевидно что получите ошибку

Comment: никакой ошибки. просто не происходил апгрейд протокола на нужный. Все работает кстати на AWS. С поддоменом все заработало с той же конфигурацией